# How Can I Download Videos Which Are Streaming from mms Protocol?

Tags: video, download, mms

There is a website which provides a Local TV's Shows Archive.

I Can watch them with Windows Media Player, it buffers there. i can see that it's using for ex. mms://abc.com/video.wmv address.

How Can I Download That Video ?

- I asked them, they would allow us to record from the screen!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mms://` is streaming protocol and, thus, media session is not necessarily backed by a file. For instance, it could be a live source of video/audio too. On your end you receive this stream of data and what you can do is to re-multitplex the data into a file.

[`Windows Media`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb190307.aspx) APIs let you write incoming data into a file. For example you could be using DirectShow [WM ASF Writer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) filter to do this (if your question refers to programmatic action, or otherwise you asked at wrong site).

Answer (score 1):

I find a way can handle this,use vlc.
refer to

[link](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/343062-How-to-Download-Videos-streaming-from-mms-protocol-with-%2a-wmv-format)

briefly speaking(my way):

1. Media -> Convert/Save
2. Network tab, enter mms:url, press Convert/Save
3. use raw input
4. Enter file name for local file
5. Press Save

more links:

http://sudofixit.blogspot.com/2013/07/guide-downloading-mmsrtsphttpetc.html

http://www.downloadatoz.com/howto/how-to-record-streaming-wmv-asf-mms-links-using-vlc-media-player,2657.html

Comment: I would like to download mms using VLC from command line. I have read though the help, but I coudn't get it. Do you know how to do it via command line?